# Populating a drop down menu using data from a table

Tags: php, sql

I am currently trying to populate a drop-down menu which will pass the primary key through the request stream, allowing me to retrieve relevant details based on which genre the user picks in said drop down. However, when I test my website the drop down menu appears in a list, and there are two options however they do not lead to an object not found error (which is what i'm expecting for now).

I have successfully listed relevant data in a table using and executing an SQL query, however want the table to change based on the genre which the user picks, and intend on achieving this by writing a script in the action page for the form. Would anybody be able to shed some light on this? I suspect I'm missing a tag somewhere in my select list, just can't put my finger on it! Sorry for posting bulky picture of code however I feel it is essential so you can see what things are being retrieved and stored as. Please see links for code and output.

Here is my code:

[image: Here is my code]

Here is the output:

[image: Here is the output]

I also noticed that the data is pulled from the database, and reflected on the browser successfully through looking at the page source, where you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DftW3.jpg). Any help on this would be great! thanks!

Comment: Still not very clear what really you want in the output. Could you explain bit better. Whats your expected output vs whats you are getting right now.

Comment: I want all of the genres to be displayed, and based off all the values which are stored in the 'name' row of the genre table, as this has all the genres stored.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you here, given an image of code? You need to post real code.

Comment: My flag as low quality was disputed? Look; there's no code here and only an image of it. If you reviewers can't put "2 and 2" together, then you shouldn't be reviewing.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you create on the while the select and options on the while only put the options and out of while put end of select and form is for this reason that repeat your select.

this an example

```
$smt = $connection->prepare('select exam_id, name From exam');
$smt->execute();
$data = $smt->fetchAll();
```

now you have your result in **$data array**

```
<select name="lst_exam" id="lst_exam">
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <option value="<?=$row["exam_id"]?>"><?=$row["name"]?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

good luck !!

Comment: Using this, however it says genre_id is an undefined constant in the URL value line of code